# Sum Recordsets Access 2013 VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have, lets say, 4 recordsets which I am creating like:

```
SET rs = (SELECT mySQL stuff)
```

This recordset is changing its content with a loop because I'm changing the WHERE condition on each iteration.

My question is, how can I sum all recordset to be able to get a result? I mean something like (pseudo code):

```
DO
  SET RS = (mySQL  stuff)
  rsTotal = rsTotal + RS
LOOP
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Is there a specific field in the recordset you want to total?